# Why is my response empty from the second mongoose query? MERN-Stack

Tags: node.js, mongoose

**Goal**: Get the students based on the given library name. The student model has the library name linked in the database.

**What's happening**:
1: Retrieving the name that is linked to the given ID (library ID aquired with useParams().id).
2: Looking for all students based on that found library name.

**Result**: Empty response. I feel like the problem has to do with the line `library_name = library.name;`. Simply that value hasn't set yet when the second query starts to execute? Because when I log the result right after this line, with `res.send(library_name);` the name is showing correctly.

```
app.get("/students/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  let library_name = "";
  LibraryModel.findById(id, (err, library) => {
    library_name = library.name;
  });
  
  StudentModel.find({library: library_name}, (err, students) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.send(students);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. `library_name` gehts only set in the callback function you passed, which happens after the `StudentModel.find(...)` gets called. Basically you are currently performing these 2 calls in parallel.
There are three ways to resolve this issue.

**Moving second call to callback function**

```
app.get("/students/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  let library_name = "";
  LibraryModel.findById(id, (err, library) => {
    library_name = library.name;
    StudentModel.find({library: library_name}, (err, students) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      } else {
        res.send(students);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**Use promises**
To avoid what's known as "callback hell" can you also use promises instead of callback functions and await them:

```
app.get("/students/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  try {
    const library = await LibraryModel.findById(id);
    const students = await StudentModel.find({library: library.name});
    res.send(students);
  } catch (err) {
    res.send(err);
  }
});
```

**Use a single aggregation pipeline**
You can also merge these two separate databases queries into a single aggregation pipeline. You would need to first use `$lookup` and afterwards use $match to filter for the specific entries. Nevertheless there is additional information on the schemas needed in order to build this query.

**Another Hint**
I assume you are trying to create a RESTful API. You might want to review your path structure, since a RESTful approach would expect the ':id' to be the ID of a student, not the ID of a library.
It looks like GET '/libraries/:id/students' makes more sense in your case.

Comment: I thought I tried that first option already, which ended up into the same result. But now it works! Thanks for the help, and I will for sure change my paths so it will make more sense.